# The property could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was trying to change a SQL Server database while working on a project using Entity Framework. However, when I altered the table, and added 1 string column `Email`, the whole thing crashed with exception that doesn't make any sense.

I have tried to add some light changes, but it has no effect.

The exception:

> System.Exception: "Couldn't retrieve entities: The property 'Users.Email' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Here is the `DbContext`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace PlanetariumModelsFramework
{
    public class PlanetariumServiceContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<PlanetariumServiceContext>(null);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Performance> Performances { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Poster> Posters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tier> Tiers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Hall> Halls { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Users model class:

```
namespace PlanetariumModelsFramework
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string UserPassword { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string UserRole { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Repository class, where the error occurs:

```
namespace PlanetariumRepositories
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly PlanetariumServiceContext RepositoryPlanetarium;

        public Repository(PlanetariumServiceContext repositoryPatternDemoContext)
        {
            RepositoryPlanetarium = repositoryPatternDemoContext;
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                return RepositoryPlanetarium.Set<TEntity>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Couldn't retrieve entities: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                await RepositoryPlanetarium.AddAsync(entity);
                await RepositoryPlanetarium.SaveChangesAsync();

                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be saved: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }        

        public async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                RepositoryPlanetarium.Update(entity);
                object p = await RepositoryPlanetarium.SaveChangesAsync();

                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be updated: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> DeleteAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(AddAsync)} entity must not be null");
            }

            try
            {
                RepositoryPlanetarium.Remove(entity);
                object p = await RepositoryPlanetarium.SaveChangesAsync();
                return entity;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(entity)} could not be deleted: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`UsersRepository` class which inherits it (optional):

```
using PlanetariumModels;

namespace PlanetariumRepositories
{
    public class UsersRepository : Repository<Users>, IUsersRepository
    {
        public UsersRepository(PlanetariumServiceContext repositoryPatternDemoContext) : base(repositoryPatternDemoContext)
        {
        }

        public Task<Users> GetByUsernameAsync(string username)
        {
            return base.GetAll().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username == username);
        }

        public Task<Users> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
        {
            return base.GetAll().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == email);
        }

        public new List<Users> GetAll()
        {
            return base.GetAll().ToList<Users>();
        }
    }
}
```

My SQL Server table creating script:

[image: Database Table "Users" Screenshot]

I tried to change type to `System.String`, tried to change its type but nothing works. And, honestly, I don't have any idea cause this error is making literally no sense.

Comment: In a new project pointing to a new database add your entities one-by-one.  You'll either find the issue, or end up with a self-contained repro you can add to your question.

Comment: The thing is, the problem is caused only by new, just-added field "Email", and I just cannot understand what is wrong with it, especially when there are 3 more field just like this one.

Comment: Nothing in your example stands out. Try backing out the change to the entity and repository and try to incrementally apply the change again. The error looks more like an issue where the entity mapping is thinking Email is a reference rather than a string value. Check if you have any entity type mapping or OnModelCreating initialization that might be trying to set up something around an Email.

Comment: And when you extract the entity model into a new, simple solution and the problem doesn't reproduce, you've made progress.

Comment: Have you added the Email field properly with migrations? If you use Code First, you can add the field to the class and run the command to add Migration and update the db (not add the database column manually)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your tips in comments.

The problem was **manual alteration of database**, which is forbidden when using ORM frameworks, like **EntityFramework**.

Simple migration fixed the issue completely.

For that, I had to open package manager in **View -> Package Manager Console**.

And enter next 2 commands for migrating:

`Add-Migration <MigrationName>`

And...

`update-database <MigrationName>`